# jQuery click handler doesn't work if inside jsTree

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

My question first. **How to make buttons 'inside jsTree' work?** It worked with `onclick` defined.

But now I used a jQuery handler for a click on buttons. Works fine. See sample http://jsfiddle.net/radek/5xym7/4/

I copied the handler definition (below) to my existing code (bit big to copy it here & not sure which part I need to provide to debug the issue)

```
$('button[type=button]').click(function(){
    var params = $(this).val();
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML+="<BR>"+params.split('|')[0]+" - "+ params.split('|')[1]+" - "+ $(this).next().prop('checked');

});
```

how the page look like

[image: how the page look like]

But it doesn't work for buttons that are inside [jsTree](http://jstree.com), On the other hand buttons outside `<div id='jstree'></div>` work with my handler.

html for buttons inside jsTree

```
<button value="login|basic" class="run square_button button_background" type="button"> run </button>
<input name="restore" title="restore before ant run" type="checkbox">
```

html for buttons outside jsTree

```
    <button class='run square_button button_background button' id='search' type='button' value='Search'>
      Search
    </button>
```

Comment: could you please update the fiddle with the full code that you want to implement or have modified ?

Comment: any idea how I can include jstree.js in fiddle?

Comment: I added the jstree in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sD6JB/22/

Comment: I don't know if it's important for my question but I think I need https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid to be added too. How can I do that? How do I reference these added resources?

Comment: you need to add the remote URL of the js file on the left hand side resources area of JSFIDDLE page.

Comment: By the way, this is a grid extension for the JSTREE. Do you need to display your data in a grid?

Comment: I don't know how to make it work. I guess 'only' the data part needs some tweaking http://jsfiddle.net/radek/T44Xs/1/ if you can have a look

Comment: If I need grid? I think so ... http://i.stack.imgur.com/aLlp9.png

Comment: I understood what you want to achieve. You dont need the GRID.

Comment: so you understood what my question is about? any idea how I can make the fiddle example working?

Comment: i will be back in half an hour. Urgent work. you can contact me on sujitagarwal.com@gmail.com.

Comment: I got the jsfiddle to work. I updated jsfiddle url in the question...

Comment: yes i saw it. Now it seems that your problem is to make the ajax loaded button to work. isnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you bind to the click event from $(document).ready(), but initialize your jsTree object outside the $(document).ready() function. The jsTree creating block will execute as soon as that part of the source is loaded, while the $(document).ready() will execute later, upon the whole DOM is loaded. So essentially the jsTree contained buttons do not exist yet, when you try to bind to their click event.

Two easy ways to remedy this:

- use jQuery's [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to allow binding of dinamically created DOM nodes
- reorganize your code, so the jsTree initialization also takes place in your $(document).ready(), and bind to the click event after the jsTree is created

I did the latter to your fiddle, it seems to work fine now. http://jsfiddle.net/5xym7/6/

Comment: great explanation. Still have two questions. Which fix is 'better' if we even can use the word better. Any suggestions how/where I can learn more on what you just taught me? Thank you.

Comment: In fact I had jsTree definition inside .ready function in my code. I changed is somehow in jsfiddle. To fix it in my code I had to change the order of jstree definition (comes first now) and my button handler (comes second now)....

Comment: In this case I'd stick to simply organizing the code in the proper order. The live() event is generally used when nodes are dynamically added to the DOM much later after the document is loaded. A good example would be user interaction triggering adding new nodes - in your example, a user clicking a button would result adding an extra node to your tree. That situation would definitely call for the live() approach. Be aware of the caveats when using live(), check the linked documentation page.